# Составте схему предложения, обозначив его грамматические основы

Tags: общие-вопросы

Прекрасная поэзия Блока, как и всякое искусство, живёт, и ей суждена вечная молодость.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что д/з